# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same port with Jetty --- identifying http vs. https from the Request

Tags: java, redirect, jetty

Starting with Jetty 9.4.? it is possible to run HTTP and HTTPs on the same port. [The gist of it is](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-io-arch-connection-factory-detecting):

```java
HttpConnectionFactory http = new HttpConnectionFactory();
SslConnectionFactory https = new SslConnectionFactory(sslCtxFactory, http.getProtocol());
DetectorConnectionFactory conFactory = new DetectorConnectionFactory(https);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, conFactory, http);
```

Since I only want to serve HTTPS, I would like to redirect each and every `http://host:port/stuff` to `https://host:port/stuff`. I know how to redirect with either subclass of `RedirectRule` or just with a handler called early.

The thing I am struggling with is: how do I figure out from the request that the connection is HTTP and not HTTPS?

When I look at the `Request` in the debugger, I found no hints, everything looks as if it is http **even if the connection is https**, `Request.isSecure()` is false, scheme is `http` and so on. The best thing I could come up with was:

```java
if (Request.getHttpChannel().getEndPoint() instanceof SslConnection.DecryptedEndPoint())
```

Here is an annotated and clipped stack trace showing how my handlers are wrapped into each other:

```java
at server.HttpToHttpsRedirectRule.matchAndApply(HttpToHttpsRedirectRule.java:34)
         "^^ Here I do the matchAndApply myself and then use a jetty RedirectRule.apply"
         "The redirect works OK, but figuring whether it is HTTPS does not work"
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RuleContainer.apply(RuleContainer.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RuleContainer.matchAndApply(RuleContainer.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:766)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at server.LogHandler.handle(LogHandler.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
                                   "^^^ the outermost handler"
[clip]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
                           "^^^ we decoded the ssl and feed the lower levels plain HTTP"
[clip]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$1.run(SslConnection.java:146)
                           "^^^ we are in SSL"
```

It is in my `HttpToHttpsRedirectRule` where I would like to figure out which connection it is. Is there a saner solution than the `instanceof` mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the original scheme (and possibly more) information is kept, it is necessary to add a [`SecureRequestCustomizer`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SecureRequestCustomizer.html) to the http configuration like this:

```java
HttpConfiguration httpConf = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
HttpConnectionFactory http = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConf);
SslConnectionFactory https = new SslConnectionFactory(sslCtxFactory, http.getProtocol());
DetectorConnectionFactory conFactory = new DetectorConnectionFactory(https);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, conFactory, http);
```

The crucial hint was found [in the jetty mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-users/msg06712.html).